problem 8080 already listening java spring
my port 8080 in java Spring so never disconnects. The process remains open even if I stop the application. Which means that when I launch the project and restart it a second time after a code modification, I am shown that it is already listening. It's the same project. I therefore have to go to currport to stop the process each time a line of code changes if I restart the project. If I change the port in application.properties, all the ports that I indicate are displayed "already listening" while ultimately, currport does not find any process on these ports. So I waste a lot of time killing the 8080 process on currport between each launch OF THE SAME PROJECT, something I never did before, I have java on 2 other PCs and it doesn't do that, I can re-run a project without kill the process. When I launch my project, it listens on one port, as long as I don't stop it, whether I launch my project 1 time or 10 times, the listening is the same. I don't know what change there was, but it affects all my spring projects only on the 8080, all other projects which launch a web service on another port do not have this problem. I've never had this problem before.
2024-04-13T15:03:49.253+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.calcul.CalculApplication     : Starting CalculApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 4584 (C:\Users\chres\Documents\jetBrainProjects\intellij-idea-projects\calcul\target\classes started by chres in C:\Users\chres\Documents\jetBrainProjects\intellij-idea-projects\calcul)
2024-04-13T15:03:49.256+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.calcul.CalculApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-13T15:03:49.314+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-04-13T15:03:49.315+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-04-13T15:03:50.575+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-04-13T15:03:50.587+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-13T15:03:50.588+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-04-13T15:03:50.637+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-13T15:03:50.639+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1322 ms
2024-04-13T15:03:51.267+02:00  WARN 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2024-04-13T15:03:51.288+02:00  WARN 4584 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
2024-04-13T15:03:51.302+02:00  INFO 4584 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-13T15:03:51.323+02:00 ERROR 4584 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.912 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-13T15:03:51+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0


even if I change the port in application.properties, it gives me the same problem, all the ports that I put are already listening while no process with these ports exists.
it is not another process which can be incriminated, because when I stop the process on port 8080 via currport, my project runs again, but I restart it just after, it gives me an error again because port busy, so before restarting my project which is already listening, I have to stop the process manually, can you imagine doing this every time you modify your code?
pressing the red button to stop the process has no effect.
thanks

To solve this first you need to open your Command Line (cmd) and type:
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
This will identify the process ID that  is using the 8080 port,
Then on the same comand line type the following command:
taskkill /PID  yourProcessNumber /F
Where yourProcessNumber must be replaced by the process number you just identified previously.
I hope this helps
The number 31420 would be the process id number in my case
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/939uM.png

I always have to delete the process each time the project runs, despite the command line
